# Get number of rows of an event already in a table before inserting a new dataset?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I have a table consisting of three values

1. ID of the participant
2. ID of the courseevent
3. Mark

For each `courseevent`, there are only 15 people allowed

How can I check this using Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

The most important aspect of this problem is making it work in a multi-user environment.

Oracle only allows READ COMMITTED and SERIALIZED isolation levels.  There are no phantom or dirty reads, and no mechanism for "peeking" at uncommitted sessions.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/consist.htm#BABEAFAH).

Which means this statement

```
select courseevent, count(*) 
from courseparticpants
group by courseevent;
```

will show you how many records have been committed.  If you go on to insert a record you could still insert the sixteenth booking, if someone else commits their work in the interim. Conversely you may decide that the course is already full when in fact somebody is about to delete a row.

To control this you need to serialize access to the `courseparticpants` table, so that only one session may insert records into it at a time.  There are various ways to do this but the safest is:

```
lock table courseparticpants exclusive nowait;
```

If you fail to get the lock you know another session is already working on it.  Otherwise you can run your count, insert a new booking and do whatever else is required with the confidence that your rule is not broken.

It is important not to freeze on to the lock for too lock, for obvious reasons: nobody else can do their work on the table.  A slightly less obtrusive mechanism would be to lock the relevant record in the parent table; I didn't propose this first because I didn't want to make assumptions about your data model.

```
select whatever
from courseevents
where courseevent = :p1
for update nowait;
```

This would allow other sessions to book participants for another event.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2130052).

Both these solutions entail writing a program unit - say in PL/SQL - to manage the transaction.

> "is there a possibility to solve this with constraints?"

No, Oracle does not allow SQL in its CHECK constraints.  Standard SQL has the concept of ASSERTIONS but Oracle has not implemented them.

One possible solution would be to make `participantid` a count within `courseevent`, so you could enforce a check constraint

```
check ( participantid <= 15)
```

However, you would still need to do all the locking and stuff to get an accurate figure for the current number of participants so that your `n+1` was correct.

Comment: A less sweeping method of handling the serialisation would be to use DBMS_Lock, constructing a lock name that is unique for the courseevent with a call to DBMS_Lock.Allocate_Unique(lockname => to_char(courseevent,'"CP"FM000000000000'), ... etc).

Comment: @Scotch - because a trigger doesn't address the multi-user aspect.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - I agree that is an option, but I tailored my answer to the question, which I suspect is coursework.  DBMS_LOCK would be a little high-powered in that context, if only because it isn't granted by default.

Comment: Extra credit for homework, of course! There's nothing like explaining why your solution is better than the teachers for winning friends and influencing people.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)
from blah, blah, blah
```

gives you the number of existing records.

Comment: THIS IS TRUE BUT YOU SHOULD ONLY SELECT FROM ONE BLAH. ALSO CONSIDER ADDING A TRIGGER. THE TRIGGER SHOULD SELECT THE COUNT OF PARTICIOPANTS FOR EVENTS `BEFORE INSERT` AND ROLL BACK IF THERE IS ALREADY 15.

Comment: IN MY COUNTRY CAPS LOCK MEAN WHISPER

Comment: @scotch - That may be so, but in the nation of Stack Overflow it is considered polite to use sentence case.

Comment: Your answer is too simplistic. When to count? Before of after insert? what if two users add the 15nth participant?

Answer (score 0):

This shows participants in more than 15 events.

```
SELECT participant, COUNT(DISTINCT courseevent) F
FROM Table
GROUP BY participant
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT courseevent) > 15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(Col1, Col2, Col3)
    SELECT 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3'
      FROM DUAL
     WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE condition) < 15;
```

Comment: If you want you can create your own USER DEFINED FUNCTION/TRIGGER which will simply query the target table for COUNT(*) and if it is greater than say 14, you can RAISE EXCEPTION.

Comment: A link to SQL Server documentation is not always relevant to an oracle problem.

Comment: Oracle does not allow user-defined functions in check constraints, even deterministic ones.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses002.htm#sthref2067

Answer (score 0):

Regular table constraints only consider *individual* rows in isolation, but your requirement is to consider a *group of rows* together. 
Here is a rather complicated solution that uses materialized view constraints to implement the requirement. 
You can think of this as defining a constraint on a column in a result set.

```
create table course_participants(
   course          varchar2(20) not null
  ,participant     varchar2(20) not null
  ,constraint course_participants_pk primary key(course, participant)
);

-- Need this for fast refreshable mview
create materialized view log 
    on course_participants 
       with rowid(course, participant) 
       including new values;

-- A materialized view with a count of participants per course
create materialized view course_parts_max_mv
refresh fast on commit
as
select course
      ,count(*) as participants
 from course_participants
group 
   by course;

-- This is where you perform the check. 
-- I've used 2 participants to make the example easier
alter materialized view course_parts_max_mv 
  add constraint too_many_participants check(participants <= 2);
```

The above DDL creates a table and a materialized view. The materialized view will contain one row for each course along with the nr of participants. The trick is that rather than declaring the constraint on the base table, we can now declare it on the the materialized view.

```
-- One participant is ok!
insert into course_participants values('Oracle', 'Alfred');
commit;

-- Two participants are ok!
insert into course_participants values('Englis speling', 'Benjamin');
insert into course_participants values('Englis speling', 'Charles');
commit;

-- This will fail, because the count(*) for 'Economics' will return 3
insert into course_participants values('Economics', 'Alfred');
insert into course_participants values('Economics', 'Benjamin');
insert into course_participants values('Economics', 'Charles');
commit;
ORA-12008: error in materialized view refresh path
ORA-02290: check constraint (RNBN.TOO_MANY_PARTICIPANTS) violated
```

Note that the constraint is checked when you **commit** the transaction, so in the last example none of the participants will get registered.